# Set "this" to an selector inside if statement when no event listeners triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, this

I am trying to set "this" to a selector inside an if statement via jquery when there is no event listeners triggered. At the moment I have to write alot of code to achieve my behaviours as seen below

```
function show(){
    if($('input#q1Male').is(":checked")){
            //do something...
    } else {
            //do something else...
    }
    if($('input#q1Female').is(":checked")){
            //repeated do something...
    } else {
            //repeated do something else...
    }
}show();
```

If "this" can be applied inside the if statement then if would simplify and clean up the javascript. I tried looking into .call() and .apply() without much luck.

Comment: Sorry I'm finding it hard to understand your question, the code you have provided above can just be called inside of a document ready. Not sure why you would need your own show function for this.

Comment: I am trying to achieve cleaner code where I would not need to do multiple of if statements to achieve the same thing. Using "this" is the solution which I was unable achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) before calling the function to set its context(='this'), or as you said, use apply/call when calling the function.

apply/call will accept as first argument the context of the function,

E.g :

```
show.apply(wantedContext, [arg1, arg2,...]);
```

or :

```
show.call(wantedContext, arg1, arg2,...);
```

in your case wantedContext will be $('input#q1Male'), so your function will be :

```
function show(){
    if(this.is(":checked")){
            //do something...
    } else {
            //repeated do something else...
    }
}
```

and then call it using :

```
show.call($('input#q1Male'));
```

and

```
show.call($('input#q1Female'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
function show(){
    if($('input#q1Male').is(":checked")){
            //do something...
    } else {
            //do something else...
    }
}show.call(this,/*what do I require to add here?Can you jsfiddle it?*/);

Comment: i dont have the html nor i dont understand what you would like to be 'this' ?

Comment: Sorry I should of explained I would like 'this' to be input. Thank you for your help. I will look more into examples of call/apply